# ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Network is unreachable after copying VM to another host machine

Tags: git, github, ssh, windows-7, vagrant

I have just copied my Vagrant VM from one host machine to another. Both machines are running Windows 7.

One the machine I copied the VM to I get the following error when attempting to access Github.

The repo definitely exists and I have the exact same Git config on the original machine. Why would this happen? The top SO answer for this error has no effect for me.

```
[vagrant@localhost /var/www/wrestlemaniamainevent]# git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:crmpicco/wrestlemaniamainevent.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:crmpicco/wrestlemaniamainevent.git (push)

[vagrant@localhost /var/www/wrestlemaniamainevent]# git fetch origin
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Network is unreachable
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I can ping Github and when I change the URLs to https, I get this:

```
[vagrant@localhost /var/www/wrestlemaniamainevent]# ping github.com
PING github.com (192.30.252.129) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.30.252.129: icmp_seq=23 ttl=51 time=112 ms
64 bytes from 192.30.252.129: icmp_seq=24 ttl=51 time=110 ms
64 bytes from 192.30.252.129: icmp_seq=25 ttl=51 time=112 ms
64 bytes from 192.30.252.129: icmp_seq=26 ttl=51 time=111 ms
64 bytes from 192.30.252.129: icmp_seq=27 ttl=51 time=112 ms
^C
--- github.com ping statistics ---
27 packets transmitted, 5 received, 81% packet loss, time 26010ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 110.904/111.957/112.869/0.756 ms
[vagrant@localhost /var/www/wrestlemaniamainevent]# git fetch origin
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/crmpicco/wrestlemaniamainevent.git/': Failed connect to github.com:443; Network is unreachable
```

My Vagrantfile

```
unless Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-host-shell")
  raise 'vagrant-host-shell plugin is not installed!'
end

# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

PRIVATE_NETWORK_IP = "10.0.0.200"

SERVER_NAME = "crmpicco.dev"

nfs_setting = RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/ || RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /linux/

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
    # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
    # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
    # config.vm.box_check_update = false

    config.ssh.forward_agent = true

    config.vm.define "local", primary: true do |local|

        nfs_setting = RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/ || RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /linux/

        local.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest:4444, host:4444
        local.vm.network :private_network, ip: PRIVATE_NETWORK_IP

        local.vm.box = "crmpicco-centos7"
        local.vm.box_url = "http://crmpicco.com/boxes/crmpicco.box"

# If you want to keep your code local and mount onto your VM, uncomment this.
#
#        local.vm.synced_folder "./../www", "/var/www", id: "vagrant-root" , :nfs => nfs_setting,
#            mount_options: ["sync,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,rw,proto=tcp"]

        local.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
            v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
            v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 3072]
            v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", 2]
            v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--name", SERVER_NAME]
        end
    end


# If you want to keep your code local and mount onto your VM, comment this whole section
     if nfs_setting
            config.vm.provision :host_shell do |host_shell|
              host_shell.inline = 'mkdir -p /Users/Shared/crmpicco'
            end

            config.vm.provision :host_shell, run: "always" do |host_shell|
              host_shell.inline = "echo 'Waiting for NFS to be available, it can take a while'"
            end

            config.vm.provision :host_shell, run: "always" do |host_shell|
              host_shell.inline = "sleep 30"
            end

            config.vm.provision :host_shell, run: "always" do |host_shell|
              host_shell.inline = "mount -t nfs -o 'sync,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,rw' #{PRIVATE_NETWORK_IP}:/var/www/current /Users/Shared/crmpicco"
            end
     end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by creating a new Virtual Box Host-Only Adapter in the Virtualbox settings, here:

[image]

The original one wasn't recognised, so I had to create a new one.

Secondly, as FredericHenri pointed out below - on my original host (Win 7 PC) I was running Virtualbox 4.3.12, whereas on the second host (Win 7 laptop) I was running Virtualbox 4.3.16 - so I downgraded the second host too and this resolved the issue.

Comment: good, I guess it fixed the [other issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32507924/unable-vagrant-up-vagrant-vm-after-copying-over-from-another-host) too ?

Comment: @FredericHenri It had a bunch of close votes, so I just deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

**First**, did you verify its not a network issue from the new host, can you ping github from the vm on the new host ?

**Second**, if ssh has an issue (and you're not much of a network guy like me - it could be firewall issue on the new host ...), you can change to use the https version

```
run `git config --local -e`
```

you should have a section

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:crmpicco/wrestlemaniamainevent.git
```

you can change that to

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/crmpicco/wrestlemaniamainevent.git
```

**Third**, make sure vagrant is same version on both host (specially if one host runs vagrant 1.6 and the other 1.7), virtual box should be ok if different but do update the GuestAdditions if you have different version with virtual box.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I tried turning off my Windows 7 firewall temporarily to see if it was a firewall blocking situation. I also had previously tried changing to using HTTPS, but I get the error in my updated question. Any ideas?

Comment: do you have proxy or something ? ping can only test on port 80 but it connect to port 443 for https, does `curl https://github.com` returns the html page of gihub ?

Comment: @FedericHenri No, I can't curl that URL. I can do `ping crmpicco.co.uk`, however `wget http://www.crmpicco.co.uk` returns `Connecting to www.crmpicco.co.uk (www.crmpicco.co.uk)|83.125.22.146|:80... failed: Network is unreachable.`. I don't understand this?

Comment: is it working from the host ? also can you show Vagantfile to see what type of network you configure

Comment: @FedericHenri Yes, I can open Firefox and go to http://www.crmpicco.co.uk (and Github for that matter). I have updated my original question to show my Vagrantfile. I am using VirtualBox to manage the VM. Could this be an issue with my network adapter setup in Virtualbox? As I say I literally copied my `.vbox` file onto a external HDD and then moved it onto the other host and then started it with Virtualbox. I assumed this was the easiest way to move it across as I have a bunch of settings that I don't want to lose. Generally it seemed to go smoothly other than this networking problem.

Comment: clear setting vm from the box thats the whole easy point of vagrant, it does work and I use that a lot too, in this case there's an network issue, might be the bridge network is not setup the same but you're using private network. is virtual box the same version on the 2 hosts ?

Comment: @FedericHenri I'm writing this on mobile so I can't check, however if VirtualBox was a different version on the first host to the second one would this be a problem? Would you recommend using the same version? I'm not sure what you mean by clear setting vm from the box. On the second host (Win7 laptop) I connect to the WWW via wifi whereas the first and working host (Win7 desktop) connects to the WWW via w wired connection.