# I want to push a project but "Network is unreachable"

Tags: github

When I'm trying to push my project with this command

```
$ git push origin master
```

this error appear

```
ssh: connect to host example.com port 1234: Network is unreachable
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Did you first do `git add "name of project and correct project path"`?

Comment: yes i do 
0/git clone
1/git add .
2/git commit
and finally git push origin master
how can I crrect the project path

Comment: Do you have a good internet connection?

Comment: yes good connection

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505012/ssh-connect-to-host-github-com-port-22-network-is-unreachable-after-copying-vm)?

Comment: Make sure you have the `write permission` in `master` branch of that repo. Have you cloned your own repo or others repo ?

Comment: @sajib khan :
other repo

Comment: your git ip has been changed. you should change your git ip and connect again